# What is the probability of running out of cards once in a game?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are three sections in a spinner. All three of the sections are colors. 
Every time a player spins they get the card corresponding to the color the spinner lands on.

There are 10 cards in each deck. Each card in the deck is unique so no other card in the deck of that color has has the same rank. There are three such decks and all these decks have the same cards of the same ranks but each deck is of a different color. The objective is to get three cards, each of different colors but all have the same deck.

This is how I solved it but I'm not sure it's correct.

There are 10 cards in a deck and there are 3 decks. The probability of the spinner landing on a color is 100% .
Therefore the spinner would have to land on the deck 10 times before the deck runs out of time. Assuming the players don’t land on bonuses or penalties which result in returning cards to a deck the probability can be calculated in the following manner:
The amount of turns before landing on a deck can be calculated with a geometric progression. E(x) = q/p
The probability of landing on the deck: 1/3
∴ p= 1/3
The probability of not landing on the deck: 2/3
∴ q= 2/3

E(x) = q/p = 2

So the estimated number of turns before landing on the deck is 3 turns
∴To land on a deck 10 times we would need the game to take longer than 20 turns.
The probability of a game finishing in 20 turns:

After 30 turns each player should have 10 cards so the probability that you have won within 30 turns can be found using hypergeometric distributions:
There are 3 cards you want and a total of 30 cards you could have had.

(3C3 * 27C7)/30C10 = 2.96%

So, the probability of running out of cards once is : 1-0.0296
=0.9704 or 97.04%

This is assuming that other players don't have the card you want.

But this doesn't answer it properly because, this is for one card, the game can be one by getting three of any rank.

Comment: To win, a player must get $3$ cards of the same rank (with three different colors), right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I don't think I explained it so well.

Comment: But it can be any $3$ cards of the same rank, not necessarily matching the first card drawn by that player, right?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal. But I don't know how to calculate that so I tried to calculate what I could. Could you show me how?

Comment: I have a few questions about the rules . . .

Comment: Why does the spinner have $4$ sections? Shouldn't it be only $3$?

Comment: The fourth section has no relevance for this question so I didn't want to include it and cause further confusion.

Comment: So if a player spins and gets the $4$th section, what happens?

Comment: What do you mean $1/2\ 110=120$?  You still haven't answered what cards you need to win.  Do you just need one card of each color, or do you need three of matching ranks?  Or do you need to match the rank of the first card you drew?  You also haven't explained where you got your calculation.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: Writing meaningful formulas may help people understand what you mean. It helps if the formulas use well-formatted mathematical notation, which you can learn to write on this site starting here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: If the spinner lands on the 4th section, they get bonuses like seeing other players cards which have no impact on the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1/2 * 120

Comment: So if a player spins and gets the $4$th section, the player spins  again? If not, that would mean the players doesn't get a new card.

Comment: There are 10 cards in each deck. Each card in the deck is unique so no other card in the deck of that color has has the same rank. There are three such decks and all these decks have the same cards of the same ranks but each deck is of a different color. The objective is to get three cards, each of different colors but all have the same deck.

Comment: Also, what happens if a player spins and gets a color for a deck which has no remaining cards (all were previously drawn)?

Comment: If the player spins the fourth section, the player doesn't get a card. It becomes the next players turn. I assumed that the players never land on the fourth section. It's unrealistic but I couldn't solve it without that assumption.

Comment: Then you should revise the rules so there are only $3$ sections.

Comment: The original question was: What's the probability of winning before a deck runs out of cards. I determined that the number of turns before that occurs is 30 turns. So, it's unlikely that the deck will run out before 30 turns.

Comment: You're right. I changed it.

Comment: What does the problem come from? Is it an exercise from a book?

Comment: I changed it to the original question. No, it doesn't come from a book, it's the probability calculation for a game.

Comment: I think if the rules would be better as: If a player spins and gets a color for a deck which is empty, they lose their turn. Then the problem would be to find the probability that someone wins before all $3$ decks run out.

Comment: There's rules for the deck becoming empty: Players must choose two to keep and return the rest to their decks. But this doesn't affect the question. All the question asks is the probability that the cards will run out.

Comment: As regards the problem of finding the actual probability, I think you should settle for a simulation. Do you have programming ability?

Comment: I am required to find it through calculation.

Comment: So it's a HW assignment?

Comment: Its a report I have to complete so like a HW assignment.

Comment: To get started, I recommend reducing the parameters. For example, $2$ players, $2$ decks, each deck with $3$ cards.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the rules or setup. Is there any method you see to solve this? I might have to try tree diagrams if I cant find any other way

Comment: In any case, with regard to getting help from MSE, I think you should ask a new question (and perhaps delete this one), with much simpler (and clearer) rules, and small values for the parameters.

Comment: The idea of reducing the game to a toy version is to gain understanding by fully solving the toy version.

Comment: Yeah I got your point but I took cases and I think I can do it. I might delete it if I dont and post a new one.